# Securing access to internal services

Tags: linux, security, vpn, iptables, ldap

I have two Linux servers, one is at my home and one is a VPS.
The VPS need to access a LDAP directory on my home server.
I would prefer not to open internal services to the world and for that purpose I thought of two solutions (there may be more):

- Allowing only the VPS IP on the router's firewall
- Using a VPN

Since the VPS is very cheap (1 vCore, 2GB RAM), a VPN might be a little too much. Is the first solution sufficient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, the first solution is sufficient.

But, i have a VPS with the same configuration with OpenVPN on it and i don't have any problems. The VPN solution is also good if you don't want to modify your router parameters. It's also more robust : if you change VPS, ISP or if you want to add more services than LDAP, you don't have to re-configure everything.

If you want to configure OpenVPN [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) can help you.